# Проверка группы пользователя ActiveDirectory средствами MS SQL

Tags: windows, sql-server, active-directory, windows-server-2012

Пытаюсь следующей командой получить входит ли пользователь в группу Active Directory:

```
IF IS_MEMBER ('Domain\Администраторы домена') = 1
  PRINT 'GOOD'
```

Но к сожалению результата не получаю, хотя являюсь членом данной группы. Где может крыться ошибка?

Сервер: Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Хмм... а что возвращает `SELECT IS_MEMBER('Domain\Администраторы домена')`? И что возвращают `SELECT SUSER_NAME()` и `SELECT * FROM sys.login_token` ?

Comment: Ты sysadmin на сервере?

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. На сервере необходимо использовать windows-аутентификацию

Answer (score 1):

Если есть сомнения насчёт принадлежности текущего пользователя к группе, можно сделать следующие проверки.

Во-первых, посмотреть - а что, собственно, возвращает функция `IS_MEMBER` для интересующей группы, и что за логин используется (функция `SUSER_NAME`):

```sql
SELECT
    [isMember] = IS_MEMBER(N'Domain\Администраторы домена'),
    [login] = SUSER_NAME()
```

Если `IS_MEMBER` для Windows-группы возвращает *NULL*, значит указана несуществующая группа, или для доступа к SqlServer используется не Windows-логин, а Sql-логин (при использовании доменного Windows-логина `SUSER_NAME` вернёт *Domain\UserName*, а при использовании Sql-логина - соответствующий *SqlLoginName*).

Во-вторых. Если всё же используется Windows-логин, но `IS_MEMBER` возвращает *0*, то можно проверить токены, связанные с логином, обратившись к *sys.login_token*:

```sql
SELECT name, type
FROM sys.login_token
```

Если пользователь не состоит в интересующей группе, то соответствующий токен будет отсутствовать в результатах запроса.

Если пользователь состоит в группе (`IS_MEMBER` возвращает *1*) - токен должен присутствовать:

```
name                    type
----------------------- --------------
Domain\UserName         WINDOWS LOGIN
public                  SERVER ROLE
sysadmin                SERVER ROLE
Domain\Domain Users     WINDOWS GROUP
Domain\Domain Admins    WINDOWS GROUP   <--- интересующий токен
...
```